# Converting redis data to MySql

Tags: mysql, caching, redis, predis

I have stored data in `Redis` and it growed by the time and it's now larger that 1GB that need a lots of RAM(Bigger than 4GB) after loading to RAM. I want to convert this data from `Redis` to MySql and serve from there instead of RAM. But I cant find a way for it. What I have to do?

Comment: Without knowing what data you're currently caching, we can't give an answer.  Note that Redis and MySQL are very different technologies.  A lookup in MySQL might typically take 100 times longer than in Redis.

Comment: I store some city names as keys and their geocode information as value. My cloud provider cant give me more than 4GB and right now all of my RAM filled with redis data and I cant get response from the Redis. I know MySql is slower but temporarily can solve this problem for me. I tried set maxmemory for Redis and store some of redis data in the disk swap area but it doesn't work and I think because current data is larger than maxmemory, it doesn't work. I don't know what I have to do